# Can "historical background" refer to historical information irrelevant to the topic?

Tags: word-usage

Someone answered a question based on what I am pretty sure is irrelevant historical information, I said:

> I'm sorry, I don't see the connection between the (interesting)
> **historical background** given and the sentence.

Is using *background* correct here or should I say *information* since I think what the person said was irrelevant?

Comment: To all intents and purposes, ***background*** information is ***always*** relevant. Anything that wasn't contextually relevant would simply be ***[co]incidental***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the meanings of **background** is "information essential to understanding of a problem or situation" [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/background). At the very least **background** is "the circumstances or events antecedent to a phenomenon or development" (same source).

So calling the historical information "background" implies that it is at least somewhat relevant. What you said may have been confusing because you seemed to be acknowledging the relevance of the historical information and questioning it at the same time.